# Can I modify image's pixel value?

Tags: image-processing, go

I would like to do sth like this in Go:

```
for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
    for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
            // something similar to this:
            src_img[x, y] = color.Black
    }
}
```

is it possible to do this, importing only "image", "image/jpeg", "image/color"?

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "image"
        "image/color"
)

func main() {
        const D = 12
        img := image.NewGray(image.Rect(1, 1, D, D))
        for x := 1; x <= D; x++ {
                img.Set(x, x, color.Gray{byte(2 * x)})
        }
        for x := 1; x < D; x++ {
            fmt.Printf("[%2d, %2d]: %5v\n", x, x, img.At(x, x))
        }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/e07G1_zUZ8)

---

Output:

```
[ 1,  1]: {    2}
[ 2,  2]: {    4}
[ 3,  3]: {    6}
[ 4,  4]: {    8}
[ 5,  5]: {   10}
[ 6,  6]: {   12}
[ 7,  7]: {   14}
[ 8,  8]: {   16}
[ 9,  9]: {   18}
[10, 10]: {   20}
[11, 11]: {   22}
```

---

Recomended reading [The Go image package](http://golang.org/doc/articles/image_package.html) article (additionally to the [godocs](http://golang.org/pkg/image)).

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to modify pixels' value of image loaded from file, not creating a new one

Comment: What's the difference? Use image.Decode to load the picture, type assert it to the proper type and use the .Set method as seen above.

Answer (score 1):

The [image.RGBA](http://golang.org/pkg/image/#RGBA) type is the preferred way to store images in memory if you want to modify them. It implements the [draw.Image](http://golang.org/pkg/image/draw/#Image) interface that has a convenient method for setting pixels:

```
Set(x, y int, c color.Color)
```

Unfortunately not all decoders are returning the images in the RGBA format. Some of them are leaving the image in a compressed format where not every single pixel is modifiable. That's much faster and fine for a lot of read-only use-cases. If you want to edit the image however, you might need to copy it. For example:

```
src, _, err := image.Decode(file)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
rgba, ok := src.(*image.RGBA)
if !ok {
    b := src.Bounds()
    rgba = image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, b.Dx(), b.Dy()))
    draw.Draw(rgba, rgba.Bounds(), src, b.Min, draw.Src)
}
// rgba is now a *image.RGBA and can be modified freely
rgba.Set(0, 0, color.RGBA{255, 0, 0, 255})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is no other way to edit the image without copying it? My app will be procesiing the images but certainly I will connect it with some C or C++ code. I have to make some tests how Go is responsive and when I use a for ex. 1600x1000 picture the effect is great, but when I use a big and heavy one (5400x3600) it slows down. And I could have about 40 images like this in the future so it's getting complicated to copy 40 images...